# Getting XML snippets using XPATH Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

Is it possible to get XML snippets using XPATH in javascript (`evaluate` function, Chrome)?

How to do it?

Keep getting errors in every approach I've used.

Comment: Can you tell us in which enviroment you want to use Javascript and XPath? As you mention `evaluate`, for Mozilla browsers see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate and post details of code used and errors you get in case the documentation does not help.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hey Martin, thanks for a reply, i am targeting chrome. it seems to do something here, but it returns error when I am trying to run examples from Mozilla docu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<root><foo bar="baz">whatever</foo></root>', 'application/xml');
var xpathResult = xmlDoc.evaluate('//foo[@bar = "baz"]', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
while ((el = xpathResult.iterateNext()) != null) {
  alert(el.textContent);
}
```

Works fine for me with Firefox and Chrome.